# Could not succeed in rollback database transactions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For the trail purpose to check how to rollback deleted transaction in SQL Server i have created a table in my database and then inserted some records in it. Then i issued delete command to delete these records, after that i applied `Rollback` command to recover deleted records but could not succeeded

PS: The whole operation is performed within the `begin` transaction

Here is the scenario:

[image]

[image]

While i have issued `SELECT` command to see the records.

Comment: Was there anything in the table to begin with? A true test checks the state _before_ not just after. Your full script should be something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student; BEGIN TRAN; delete from student; rollback tran; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student;`

Comment: OMG dude! you deleted all the student records! but anyways dude, yeah, listen to @Nick.McDermaid, maybe there were no records to begin with? and if that's not the case, know that it is quite impossible for a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` to not be rolled back! i mean, even if your machine suddenly turns off, all that stuff will be rolled back! or even if you accidentally try to close all your SSMS tabs, SSMS will ask you what you wanna do with the uncommitted transactions.

Comment: Hi Nick, i have executed the **Select * from student** to view the table record. Is it wrong?

Comment: You need to run it _first_ to confirm there are records there in the first place, _then_ test your delete and rollback. _then_ run it again. Otherwise you're not proving anything. The table was probably already empty.